# list of duplicates on python

Tags: python, list, sage

If I have a list, how do I create from it a list of lists of duplicates?
For instance, if I have the list

```
L = [1,2,1,3,4,2,1,4]
```

I want the output to be

```
L1 = [[1,1,1], [2,2], [3], [4,4]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be about a hundred ways of doing this. Here's one. If you want more, since this is really a Python question add the Python tag to your question.

```
>>> L = [1,2,1,3,4,2,1,4]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(L)
>>> counts
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 4: 2, 3: 1})
>>> L1 = [ [ _ ]*counts[_] for _ in counts.keys() ]
>>> L1
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3], [4, 4]]
```

Comment: Great answer, I found your list comp a little difficult to read with the formatting, so maybe formatted like this will help OP `L1 = [[key] * counts[key] for key in counts.keys()]`

Comment: @flybonzai: I don't know! I'm all for alternative though.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the `collections.Counter` answers, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

L = [1,2,1,3,4,2,1,4]
grouped = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(L))]
print(grouped) # -> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3], [4, 4]]
```

Comment: Much better answer!

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @Bill_Bell's answer.

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(L)
>>> counts
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 4: 2, 3: 1})
>>> L2 = [[a]*b for (a,b) in counts.items()]
>>> L2
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3], [4, 4]]
```